# wp_editor: How to load wp_editor on demand using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, wp-editor

I am trying to load wp_editor on demand using jquery/javascript.

Somehow I got success using following code but it does not save changed data in the element.

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, textarea_id);
```

I'll really appreicate any contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `wp_editor()` it loads WordPress default visual editor.
You must load:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/j7brgyL2/

```
<textarea id="test">Easy features.</textarea>
```

**And the code is**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "none"
    });
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'test');
});
```

Simply use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'textarea_id');
```

Here is another example example:

```
<textarea name="sectionContent_1" id="sectionContent_1"></textarea>
```

script:

```
var textAreaID = 'sectionContent_' + sectionID;
$(this).parent()
    .find('.sectionOptions')
    .html(ctHolder).ready(
        function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, textAreaID); 
        }
    );
```

and the most simple way is

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, id);
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
```

Comment: why did you use category and action? why do we need that? I just need to convert textarea into wp_editor

Comment: that is an example bro

Comment: but how can I implement this in my case?

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked it's good but It is not giving me updated value from the editor. Actually I need to submit form after editing. http://jsfiddle.net/4m91yhug/2/

Comment: Hey man you did wrong check this its working http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/brntmuux/

Comment: Please type something and then click button, you will notice that you will still get old text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98860/discussion-between-user2899728-and-firefog).